# Is there a way to make views_pre_build fire only once?

Tags: views, ajax

In Drupal 7, I am trying to set an ajax view's current_page when it first displays, which I can do, but of course it will always go to that page regardless of the input from the pager. The goal is simply to have the view jump to the last item when first displayed.